# ASP.net LINQ: return items where id equals a variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I use asp.net c# with webforms and I work with the dal+bll structure. This is my situation:

I have a starting page with 8 buttons, when I click on one of this buttons, I go to a page list.aspx.

On this page, there is data returned from the database with this LINQ code:

```
    var result = (from b in dc.Businesses
                  select b).ToList();
    return result;
```

This all works as it should. However, I want to make it so that if I click on button1, only the records with businessType "NighShop" are returned. When I click on button2, only records with idName "Bar" are returned etc. It would be stupid to make 8 different pages + DAL&BLL's for this.

So I figure the LINQ (in the DALBusiness.cs class layer) should be something like this:

```
    var result = (from b in dc.Businesses where b.BusinessType == aVariableValue
                  select b).ToList();
    return result;
```

And that variableValue can be altered whenever the user presses one of the 8 buttons. But I have no experience with this, so I don't know how to do this.

I tried to declare the var when I press on a button (on index page):

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var keuze = "Nachtwinkel";
}
```

But if I try:

```
public IList<Business> selectAll()
{
    var result = (from b in dc.Businesses where b.BusinessType == keuze
                  select b).ToList();
    return result;
}
```

On theDALBusiness.cs class layer, then it doesn't know the var keuze. I'm new to asp.net, so the answer might be really easy after all.

Comment: your example looks fine - what problem are you running into?

Comment: Can you post the implementation for `Business` or `BusinessType`?

Comment: Maybe `==` operator is comparing the references? What is the type of `BusinessType` property?

Comment: I extended the originak post, i hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. You need to store your Keuze value somewhere accessible to SelecAll().

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Session["keuze"] = "Nachtwinkel";
}

public IList<Business> selectAll()
{
    var result = (from b in dc.Businesses where b.BusinessType == Session["keuze"]
                  select b).ToList();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: when i try this it says the name Session does not exist in this namespace.

Comment: Oh, I've stupid the LINQ is not on the list.aspx page itself, it's in the DALBusiness.cs layer. I think that's why it doesn't recognize Session?

Comment: Fixed it! I was able to get through the session in a class with httpContext.Current.Session["sessionName"]

Answer (score 2):

If it does not know that variable try making a method instead that compares to the 
`anIdVariable` will something like this work it's the same thing as the Linq but in more of a Method format just as an example

```
public bool FilterByBusinessTypeID(dc.Business dcBusiness)
{
   return dcBusiness.ID == anIdVariable;
}
var result= BusinessType.Where(FilterByBusinessTypeID).First();
```

Answer (score 2):

in the LINQ query it will evaluate references as typed. If you specify `b.BusinessType == x` and you have a type or entity "BusinessType", you will need to pass the object reference (i.e. x has to be typed "BusinessType"). You can get around this by doing something like the following:

```
//this line in your OnClick function
keuze = "MyBusinessTypeName";

//this line in your data handler
var result = (from b in dc.Businesses where b.BusinessType.BusinessTypeName == keuze
              select b).ToList();
```

As Erix says, the keuze variable needs to be accessible to both. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm following your reasoning, but where does BusinessTypeName comes from in thedata handler line?

Comment: Oh, I've stupid the LINQ is not on the list.aspx page itself, it's in the DALBusiness.cs layer. I guess this changes how to fix this?

Comment: Just tried the code on the listpage, and then it works. If we can just find a way now to also make it work on the DALBusiness.cs layer, then my problem is fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you meaning to just compare the Id's like:

```
var result = (from b in dc.Businesses where b.BusinessType.Id == anIdVariable
              select b).ToList();
return result;
```

Comment: Yes, i tried that. When i click on a button, i declare that anIdvariable = "Bar" for example, but when i try to use that var in LINQ, its doesn't know that variable.